# Adding javascript within javascript which loads another javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to dynamically add a javascript tag, whose src points to an external source, whose
result will generate some other javascript. That javascript will draw external data, a table for football teams.

If I include it with `document.write` it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var everysport_u="http://puff.everysport.com/team_puff_competitiontable_normal_script_52764:0.html";
document.write("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' charset='ISO-8859-1' src='"+everysport_u);
var everysport_r=Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
document.write("?_r="+everysport_r);
document.write("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
</script>
```

Howevery using DOM manipulation it does not.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
var everysport_r=Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
var everysport_u = "http://puff.everysport.com/team_puff_competitiontable_normal_script_52764:0.html";
script.src = everysport_u;
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementById('everysport-accordion').appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Does `#everysport-accordion` exist at the time of script execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script at http://puff.everysport.com/team_puff_competitiontable_normal_script_52764:0.html is using `document.write`. A script which uses `document.write` can only be included during the loading of the page. After the page loads, `document.write` no longer functions as expected.

It's fine to include a script which itself does DOM manipulation with DOM manipulation. But the fact of the matter is `document.write` expects to be able to write immediately to the document wherever it is located. Trying to `document.write` after the page has loaded will clear the current page and override it.

Check out this simple example: http://jsbin.com/azumus/1/ (and click **refresh** a few times).

If you do add a script which uses `document.write` to an element higher up in the page during page load, the `document.write` will write to the page, but *not where you intend it to*. `document.write` will only write where the page is currently loading; it can't be used to write into any element you want it to.

See this page for an example: http://jsbin.com/ayomoz/1/ (and view source).

### In summary

Put your `<script>` tag wherever you intend to write to the document. If you want to write to the element with id `everysport-accordion`, you need to do something like this:

```
...

<div id="everysport-accordion">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var everysport_u="http://puff.everysport.com/team_puff_competitiontable_normal_script_52764:0.html";
        document.write("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' charset='ISO-8859-1' src='"+everysport_u);
        var everysport_r=Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
        document.write("?_r="+everysport_r)
        document.write("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
    </script>
</div>

...
```